# Is creating an Object using new() operator is polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Recently I attended an interview and a question was asked to me

Is creating an Object using `new()` operator is polymorphism?

For ex:

`Employee e = new Employee();`

Is this polymorphism? (Reply with yes and no  and explain.)

I was unable to think of the answer.

As what i have read about polymorphism is compile type and runtime.

Can anybody explain?
Thanks.

Comment: No.  If you made Employee a subclass of Person and then, at some point, might either have an Employee or a GalleySlave in a reference typed Person, that would be polymorphism.

Comment: Polymorphism is where you call a method on a reference to a super class/interface and it works out that really you wanted a method which was based on the type the object really is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you assign a base class reference to a child class object then it is a form of polymorphism.

> Polymorphism, which etymologically means "many forms," is the ability
>   to treat an object of any subclass of a base class as if it were an
>   object of the base class. A base class has, therefore, many forms: the
>   base class itself, and any of its subclasses.

This is NOT an example of polymorphism

```
Employee e = new Employee();
```

but assume if Empolyee is a class, which is extended from another class called Person then this will enable polymorphism by calling the methods of Employee at the run time:

```
Person p = new Employee();
```

Read this article to learn more:

http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html

Answer (score 2):

According [java polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

> The dictionary definition of polymorphism refers to a principle in biology in which an organism or species can have many different forms or stages. This principle can also be applied to object-oriented programming and languages like the Java language. Subclasses of a class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the same functionality of the parent class.

```
Employee e = new Employee();
```

is not the example of polymorphism.
But

```
Object emp = new Employee();
```

is an example for polymorphism.Since here Subclass (`Employee`) defining its own unique behaviors and yet sharing some of the same functionality of the parent(`Object`) class.